Jhipster for Microservice to Microservice Integration
I have a requirement to call say Microservice B from another Microservice A Using REST API.
Is this supported by jHipster? I want to be able to control its definition via JDL.
Something like defining what API, what is the Payloads etc.
RestTeplate is used to Integrate
I tried https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/marketplace/details/generator-jhipster-feign-client/ but its not at all having any info on how to use it and what are the working example.

Yes, this is supported by JHipster. See the following blog post I wrote for more information:
https://auth0.com/blog/java-spring-boot-microservices/#Connect-to-Java-Microservices-with-Spring-Cloud-OpenFeign

Thanks Matt, I went through the article, it has the code on how to use the Feign to Integrate. However I did not see what entries are to be added to JDL and what are the instructions to use JHipster to generate that code. Please let me know if missed anything

You are correct. Sorry about that. The referenced blog post does not use JHipster. With JHipster, requests are proxied to the downstream microservices by Spring Cloud Gateway.
